# Sed replace only in even numbered lines of a file when replace commands are written in a file

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have all the replace commands in a file say `replace.sed` and i use it with -f flag of sed
`sed -f replace.sed InputFile`. But now i ran into a condition where i need to apply these replace rules only on even numbered lines of a given input file (i.e only on line no 2,4,6 and so on).I can not put any condition statements in `replace.sed` file as that is used by another scripts also.

Comment: An example of input and output text would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-f file` acts like an include (it *add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed*), so you can put its content inside a group of commands:

```
sed -e '2~2{' -f replace.sed  -e '}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR%2==0 {do some with lines here}' file
```

It will then change some on line 2,4,6....

eks

```
awk 'NR%2==0 {sub(/old/,"new"}1' file
```

This will replace word `old` with `new` on line 2,4,6... and then print all lines (changed and not changed)